# Show that $\lim(\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {n+1})=0$ using epsilon-delta definition.

Tags: limits

> Show that $\lim(\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {n+1})=0$ using epsilon-delta definition.

I have to show that if $n,N\in\mathbb N$ and $n\geq N$, then $\frac 1 n-\frac 1 {n+1}\leq \frac 1 N-\frac 1 {N+1}$, but I don't know how. Can someone give me some idea? Thanks.

Comment: "$\delta$" is needed for proving a limit only for real functions but for a sequence (which is a mapping $S:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$) the definition calls only for an "$\varepsilon$".
Also, the notation $\lim$ doesn't make sense without mentioning the variable, and where it tends to, namely, $\lim_{n\to\infty}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\leq\frac{1}{N(N+1)}=\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1}$$ for all $n\geq N.$

Alternatively you can use that $$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}$$ for all $n\geq N$, i.e. for $\epsilon>0$ if you choose $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then  $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "alternative". I don't immediately see how to draw the conclusion at that point.

Comment: The alternative does not really work, since $\frac{1}{N} > \frac{1}{N} - \frac{1}{N+1}$ (and you need a $<$). But the first answer is easy enough and works alright.

Comment: @MårtenW: What I meant for the inequality $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{N}$ is that he can use it as an alternative way to prove the convergence of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I edited to clarify.

Comment: @P..: Ok, I understood it more like TMM.